# Dojo 1.6 DataGrid, dojox.grid.cells.Select selection event

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

I need to implement a hierarchical choice list in my DataGrid. Depending on the value of the first column, the available options for the second column need to change. Is there any way to attach a selection listener to the DataGrid (or all cells?) and modify the options value of the second column (in this specific row) to display values depending on the first columns value?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but the dojox.grid.DataGrid has among its defined events:

```
onApplyCellEdit(inValue, inRowIndex, inFieldIndex)
```

so you can:

```
   dojo.connect(grid, 'onApplyCellEdit', 
       function(inValue,inRowIndex, inFieldIndex){
           var colObj = grid.getCell(2);
           var node = colObj.getNode(inRowIndex);
           var select = dojo.query(".dojoxGridSelect",node)[0];

           console.log(select);
       }
   );
```

as long as the field is set alwaysEditing=true

That will give you access to the node and the cell... but if you change the options it rewrites it. There should be a better way of doing it by using the dojo's methods.

http://jsfiddle.net/dacabdi89/2acjt/